# defining the operational semantics of a concurrent language

Tags: concurrency, operational-semantics

As big-step operational semantics is about evaluating an expression to a final value, can we state that for defining a concurrent language one needs small-step semantics, as concurrent programs need not result in a value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Coinductive Big-Step Semantics for Concurrency](http://cs.ioc.ee/~tarmo/papers/places13.pdf) by Tarmo Uustalu writes:

> Second, contrary to what is so often stated, concurrency is
>   not inherently small-step, or at least not more inherently 
>   than any kind of effect produced incrementally during a 
>   program’s run (e.g.,  interactive output).  Big-step semantics 
>   for concurrency can be built by borrowing the suitable 
>   denotational machinery, except that we do not want to use 
>   domains and fixpoints to deal with partiality, but 
>   coinductively defined sets and corecursion.

So the answer is that it is stated throughout the literature, but it is not true.